# ArduCAM ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I am working with an MT9J001_10MP ArduCam. I am unable to run the camera through the external trigger though. I am using the command:

```
*sudo python2.7 ./ArduCam_Ext_Trigger_Demo.py /home/pi/ArduCAM_USB_Camera_Shield/cpp_config/MT9J001_10MP.yml*.
```

This then returns the fact that a device has been found (this is good) but then later says

> *ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded*

Does anyone have a solution as to why this is happening? P.S. if I try to run the exact line in python3 instead of python2.7 I get an error that says undefined symbol: Py_ZeroStruct

Thank you in advance for your help